# Which flowers & leaves ought to be offered to Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, puja

I know of Bilva leaves and Datura flowers. Are there any other leaves & flowers which are dear to Lord Shiva?

Scriptural references and/or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Plants are not offered :D .. Only flowers are ..

Comment: @rickross Can we offer flower of any color to Lord Shiva, or it should only be white?

Comment: Bilva leaf is not a flower. And it is one of the most beloved offerings of Lord Mahadev.

Comment: @rudran only leaves and flowers (patra pushpani) but no plants 

Comment: @rishabh Lord Shiva likes white flowers the most but other color flowers are also allowed

Comment: @Rickross Alright, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lord Shiva can be worshiped with almost all flowers except Champaka and Ketaka flowers as mentioned in [Shiva Maha Purana, Section 2.1 - Rudra-saṃhitā (1): Sṛśṭi-khaṇḍa, Chapter-14](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225982.html).

> 36. Excepting the Campaka and the Ketaka there is no flower which does not appeal to Śiva. All other flowers can be used for worshipping Him.

Also, in the same chapter, when asked by Saunaka and other sages, sage Suta described the importance of various flowers in worship of Lord Shiva.

> 4. A person desirous of wealth shall worship lord Śiva with **lotuses, Bilva leaves, petals of lotuses or with Śaṅkha flowers**.
> 5. A person desirous of long life shall worship him with Dūrvā grass. A person desirous of sons shall worship him with **Dhattūra flowers**.
> 6. A Dhattūra plant with red stem is specially auspicious for worship. A worshipper using Agastya flowers will earn great fame.
> 7. Worldly pleasures and salvation will be secured by a person who worships with **Tulasī**. Great valour can be secured by worshipping with **Arka or Kubjakalhāra flowers**.
> 8. The worship with **Japā flowers (China rose)** brings about the death of enemies. **Karavīra flowers** drive away all ailments.
> 9. By worshipping with **Bandhūka flowers** the devotee will get ornaments; with **Jātī flowers** he will acquire good vehicles; with **Atasī flowers** he will attain favour of Viṣṇu.
> 10. With **Śamī leaves** he will secure salvation. With **Mallikā flowers** he will secure an auspicious woman.
> 11. With the splendid **Yūthikā flowers** he will not be deprived of a house. With **Karṇikāra flowers** he will secure plenty of garments.
> 12. With **Nirguṇḍi flowers**, his mind becomes pure in the world. A hundred thousand Bilva leaves used for worship will secure the fulfilment of all desires.
> 13. Use of lovely flowers in the form of garlands increases happiness and wealth. Use of seasonal flowers for worship yields liberation. There is no doubt in this.
> 14. The **flowers of Rājikā** bring about the death of enemies. A hundred thousand Rājikā flowers shall be used for the worship of Śiva. The benefit accruing will be very great.

<sub>Please note that, flowers mentioned here may be some different common name. Google search of these flower names can be helpful.</sub>

Comment: I have found another scriptural reference regarding the Ketaka flower in Śivapurāṇa, Vidyeśvarasaṃhitā, 8:15 - "O you Ketaka flower, you are roguish and deceitful. Go away from here. Hereafter I have no desire to include you in my worship."

Comment: @Rudran Good one!

Comment: Triyugi Narayan Mani, thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: @Rudran You are welcome.

Comment: Can we offer tulsi to Lord Shiva?

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh Yes.

Comment: Which scripture defines or mentions the concept of Shiva being Ashutosh & Shiva will be pleased by only bel leaves & water? @Triyugi Narayan Mani

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh Almost every Purana and Itihasa mention lord Shiva as Ashutosha. But if you are looking for the exact source which explicitly mention that Shiva is Ashutosha and pleased only by bell leaves and water then I have to look.