# Shiva Manasa Puja of Sri Adi Shankaracharya and the Champaka flower

Tags: shiva, worship, adi-shankaracharya, stotra

Shiva Manasa Puja of Sri Adi Shankaracharya has the verse below:

> रत्नैः कल्पितमासनं हिमजलैः स्नानं च दिव्याम्बरं
>   नानारत्नविभूषितं मृगमदामोदाङ्कितं चन्दनम् ।
>   **जातीचम्पकबिल्वपत्ररचितं पुष्पं च धूपं तथा**
>   दीपं देव दयानिधे पशुपते हृत्कल्पितं गृह्यताम् ॥
>
> ratnaiḥ kalpitamāsanaṃ himajalaiḥ snānaṃ ca divyāmbaraṃ
>   nānāratnavibhūṣitaṃ mṛgamadāmodāṅkitaṃ candanam ।
>   **jātīcampakabilvapatraracitaṃ puṣpaṃ ca dhūpaṃ tathā**
>   dīpaṃ deva dayānidhe paśupate hṛtkalpitaṃ gṛhyatām ॥
>
> Meaning: I Offer You Flowers composed of Jaati (Jasmine) (Jaati) and Champaka (Magnolia) (Champaka), along with Bilva Leaves (Bilva), and wave Incense sticks ...

But according to the scriptures the use of Champaka flowers are forbidden in the worship of Lord Shiva. Reference : [Which flowers & leaves ought to be offered to Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35403/5212) ;

> Excepting the Campaka and the Ketaka there is no flower which does not appeal to Śiva. All other flowers can be used for worshipping Him.

then what is the reason why Adi Shankaracharya mentioned Champaka flower?  Is that a possible mistake that happend later on when passing down the Stotra?

Comment: "But according to the scriptures the use of Champaka flowers are forbidden in the worship of Lord Shiva" Can you cite any reference?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā  I am unable to give an authentic reference but internet sources say about a story from Shiva Purana that involves Sage Narada.  Champaka flower is said to have been cursed just like the Ketaki flower.  Also we can see in Lord Shiva temples they don't use these two flowers. 
 http://ramaswamysastry.blogspot.com/2012/09/do-not-use-champaka-flowers-to-worship.html   https://www.hindu-blog.com/2010/02/why-champaka-flowers-are-not-used-in.html

Comment: @Paṇḍyā It's a well known while worshipping Lord Shiva which involve cursing of the flower. Anyway, I added a reference.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Thank you so much for the edit and adding the reference.